# Add new cell before each week in JTCalendar

Tags: ios, objective-c, jtcalendar

I've got a vertical scrolling JTCalendar in a ViewController and I need to add a new cell before each week.

Just imagine that each day's cell will contain a number (beside the day number) and I want to show the week's total in the new cell.

I tried adding another view with a label for each week, but it's very hard to synchronize this view's scrolling with the calendar scrolling and to keep them lined up correctly.

Any idea?

Comment: I solved the problem adding another view, parallel to the calendar, that shows the week's totals.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

At the end I had to find a workaround and created a vertical view, parallel to the calendar view, that contains one view for each calendar week, showing the totals I needed to show.